# How to position a fixed element next to a centered container

Tags: css, css-position

I want to position my fixed menu-bar just next to my centered container, but its position is relative to the view port and not to the container, so I am having problems keeping it next to the container.

What is the easiest/cleanest way to position a fixed element next to the container?

Here's my test: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10378684/index.html

**HTML :**

```
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <hgroup>
            <h3>TIA1</h3>
            <h1>Contreformes</h1>
        </hgroup>

    </header>
    <nav>
        <ol>
            <li><a href="#">Grilles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contreformes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ligne de base</a></li>
        </ol>
    </nav>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse veritatis non autem blanditiis quo rerum sint quasi architecto quibusdam rem. Quibusdam dolores aliquid eum qui impedit architecto ipsum repellendus illum!</p>    

</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: "adelle", Helvetica, serif;
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding:  8px ;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}

a:hover {
    background: rgba(223, 207, 191, 0.4);
    padding-left: 10px;
}

ol {
    color: rgba(223, 207, 191, 0.8);
    position: relative;
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 139px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: rgba(223, 207, 191, 0.15);
    position: relative;
    float: left;

}

#container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 1.0);
    height: 900px;
}

h1, h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0px;
}

h3 {
    padding-top: 15px;
}

h1 {
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}
```

Comment: use floats. in this case.. float left for menu bar and float right for the content

Comment: @DhruvenkumarShah You can't float fixed elements.

Comment: okay can you use hard pixel values? I mean it is a bad practice, or use twitter bootstrap 12column grid layout

Comment: @JOPLOmacedo Just next to it.

Comment: @DhruvenkumarShah Yep, I'm using pixels. Well, I'm trying to keep it as simple as I can.

Comment: Can you leave it position fixed then give it negative margin to pull it out to the side?

Comment: @Brant Yeah but since it's fixed, its position is relative to the viewport, not the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually quite easy to do. All you need to do is use a bit of maths with the positioning of the `nav` element. Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3suYg/embedded/result/

```
nav{
    width: 139px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -619px; /* 480(half width of 960px container) + 139(width of nav) */
}
```

Obviously though your layout choice will cause issues with smaller screens as the navigation might be partially or totally hidden from view.